# dynamic properties in ws consumer service Address

Tags: java, web-services, soap, mule

I am using Mule 3.5 and have a requirement where I need to consume a SOAP webservice for which authorization is done via the [authority part](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme) of the URL itself.

I do not have control over this API and hence cannot change it.The URL will look something like the below

```
https://2james:Mdops@allscripts/HWS61/ClinicalInfo.svc
```

Where username is 2james and password is Mdops.

The username and password will be passed on to the mule flow after which i need to connect to the SOAP webservice.

Mule documentation [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+Tips), (cheat sheet section) explains how message properties can be used to customise the http outbound url.

```
<https:outbound-endpoint address="https://#[message.inboundProperties.username]:#[message.inboundProperties.password]@api.acme.com/v1/users" />
```

I need to have similar functionality with my WS consumer, when I try this Mule fails on startup complaining that it cannot parse the URI, my configuration looks like the below

```
<ws:consumer-config name="Web_Service_Consumer" wsdlLocation="Authentication.wsdl" service="Authentication" port="BasicHttpBinding_IAuthentication" serviceAddress="https://2james:Mdops@localhost:443/HWS61/Authentication.svc" doc:name="Web Service Consumer" connector-ref="HTTP_HTTPS">
</ws:consumer-config>

<flow name="testFlow1" doc:name="testFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP" mimeType="application/json" contentType="application/json" />

        <ws:consumer config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer" operation="Logon" doc:name="Authentication" />
</flow>
```

If i change the ws:consumer-config to use message properties Mule fails to start with the below exception

```
ERROR 2014-06-24 15:53:46,771 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mule.endpoint.MuleEndpointURI.getScheme(MuleEndpointURI.java:331)
    at org.mule.module.ws.consumer.WSConsumerConfig.createOutboundEndpoint(WSConsumerConfig.java:50)
    at org.mule.module.ws.consumer.WSConsumer.createMessageProcessor(WSConsumer.java:230)
    at org.mule.module.ws.consumer.WSConsumer.initialise(WSConsumer.java:91)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
```

**

### UPDATE

**

As answered below the web consumer can work with dynamic properties, however the problem comes in when the WS Consumer refers to a HTTP connector. The reason i had to do this is because the SOAP WS depends on a truststore for authentication, the trust store can only be configured via the HTTP connector.

So my updated WS Consumer looks like this.

```
<ws:consumer-config serviceAddress="https://#[message.payload]:#[message.payload]@localhost:${port}/#[message.inboundProperties['path']]" wsdlLocation="Authentication.wsdl"
                        service="Authentication" port="BasicHttpBinding_IAuthentication" name="Web_Service_Consumer" connector-ref="HTTP_HTTPS"/>


<https:connector name="HTTP_HTTPS" cookieSpec="netscape" validateConnections="true" sendBufferSize="0" receiveBufferSize="0" receiveBacklog="0" clientSoTimeout="10000" serverSoTimeout="10000" socketSoLinger="0" doc:name="HTTP-HTTPS" >
        <https:tls-server path="E:\AppServer\client-truststore.jks" storePassword="welcome" explicitOnly="true" requireClientAuthentication="true" />
    </https:connector>
```

Comment: I have resolved my issue.To begin with remove the HTTP connector reference from the WS consumer. Add the certificate into the JDK truststore if that is not acceptable, then use a component just before the ws consumer to set the trust store details into system properties and WS consumer will use it automatically. In case someone faces same issue and cannot resolve just ping me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a dynamic address as shown here: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/c88dbfecc98e5586ee100185082c411ebb0d0f16/modules/ws/src/test/resources/dynamic-address-config.xml

Its complaining that its missing the scheme, so could you post the config for the wsconsumer config with the dynamic address?

The following should work:

```
<ws:consumer-config name="Web_Service_Consumer" wsdlLocation="Authentication.wsdl" service="Authentication" port="BasicHttpBinding_IAuthentication" serviceAddress="https://#[message.inboundProperties.username]:#[message.inboundProperties.password]@localhost:443/HWS61/Authentication.svc" doc:name="Web Service Consumer" connector-ref="HTTP_HTTPS">
</ws:consumer-config>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer and yes it does, I have further updated my question to reflect my exact scenario, I had left out of detail thinking it is non consequential